# Call custom hook inside function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i need to call my custom hook called useAxios() inside function. As i know its not available in react, but i hope there's some method that do the trick

useAxios hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const useAxios = (method: string, param: string, data: any) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    Axios({
      method: method,
      url: `https://gernagroup-server.herokuapp.com/${param}`,
      data: data,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setResponse(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { response, error };
};

export default useAxios;
```

I have to call this function, but using my hook

```
 const handleNewSale = () => {
    Axios.post("https://gernagroup-server.herokuapp.com/new-sale", {
      data: selectedValues,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        showModal(ResultType.success, "New sale added successfully!");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        showModal(ResultType.error, "Something went wrong");
      });
  };
```

I have to call this function on click

```
<Button text="New sale" onClick={handleNewSale} />
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a custom hook for you here? There might be a far better pattern for you.

Comment: You can use what react query does for a hook as a guide to how to create your own - see how you basically pass it a callback that gets invoked later (for example, on button click) - Here is one of my little tests, pretty much taken from their demo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-suspense-cmdq7l?file=/src/Posts.tsx

Comment: I didn't see where you use `useAxios` hook? Dou you mean that the function `handleNewSale` is going to be re-written using the `useAxios` hook ?

Answer (score 0):

fetchData is async, you’re missing async and await keywords in code. Same for handleNewSale.

Avoid any types.

Give your custom hook a strict return type. Also you may need an export keyword in front of the ‘const’